# How to add multiple event listeners for the same react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

How is it better to add multiple event listeners in the same component in a more reusable way?

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleVisible);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleVisible);
...
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleVisible);
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleVisible);
...

  },
```

Comment: You could create a custom hook for that.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize scroll', this.handleVisible);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom hook like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const useResizeScroll = callback => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize scroll', callback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize scroll', callback);
  }, [callback]);
};
```

Then implement it in your component like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useResizeScroll(handleVisible)

  function handleVisible() { ... }

  return (...)
}
```

**Note:**

This will required you to move over to a hooks implementation of your component.

So if you were using `this.state = { ... }`, you'll need to go learn how to make use of React's `useState` hook: [React useState Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

**UPDATE:**

If you want the hook to be more flexible, like selecting what event listeners you want the component to hook onto, then you could do this:

```
export const useResizeScroll = (eventListener, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(eventListener, callback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener(eventListener, callback);
  }, [callback]);
};
```

And then implement it like this:

```
useResizeScroll('resize scroll', handleVisible)
```

**More Advanced Use Case:**

You could also improve your custom hook by making use of React Context. Here's an example of implementing a hook that keeps track of your window width.

```
import React, { createContext, useContent, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const ViewportContext = createContext({ width: window.innerWidth })

export const ViewportProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  function handleResize() {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, [])

  return (
    <ViewportContext.Provider value={{ width }}>
      {children}
    </ViewportContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useViewport = () => {
  const { width } = useContext(ViewportContext)
  return { width }
}
```

Then you can use it in any component like this:

```
const { width } = useViewport()
```

This should provide you with enough information to build a custom hook to match your use case.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So if there are other event listeners as well I can simply add in the same hook but in the component add like this?
useResizeScroll(handleVisible);
useResizeScroll(handlehidden)
If there is another case with other callbacks?

Comment: I'll make an update for the use case of using different event listeners.

Comment: I got confused a bit. So my question was if I can call the same hook twice with different callbacks separating with a semicolon. Also shouldn't here be  return () => window.removeEventListener('eventlistener', callback); as well in the updated section?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll fix that. Why don't you combine your multiple callbacks into just one function and make that your callback?

Comment: callbacks are completely different and there is no way to mix them in one unfortunately.

Comment: Because theoretically you only need to add and remove the event listener once, so it doesn't make sense to call the hook more than once in the same component. You are more than welcome to call the hook in different components. But if you're working with just one component and you want to use multiple callbacks, then you should rather just combine the callbacks into one callback (it could be a different function).

Comment: No, there's always a way. `function mergedCallback() { callback1(); callback2(); }`

Comment: So if I merge them then how will it know which one in which scenario should be used? There are vise versa scenarios.

Comment: `function mergedCallback() { if (condition) callback1(); else callback2(); }`

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
window.addEventListener('resize scroll', callback);
```

didn't work for me.

I had to to do :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', callback);
window.addEventListener('scroll', callback);
```

But this worked :

```
window.removeEventListener('resize scroll', handleResize)
```